# Firebaseui login with social media is not responding

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I tried to integrate firebaseUi in my application. When user logins with any social media, system is not giving me an answer or data after auth state changed. Only I see the query progress bar below.

[image]

```
async ngOnInit() {
  // reset login status
  this.authenticationService.logout();
  // get return url from route parameters or default to '/home'
  this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/home';
  await firebase.auth().signOut();

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(data => {
  console.log(data);
  this.signUpWithSocialIcon(data);
});
```

}

The console does not write anything to me. But when I use

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword
```

I got response and login succesfully.

my package.json is

```
     {
      "name": "demo-simple",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "license": "MIT",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~5.1.0",
        "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.2",
        "@angular/common": "~5.1.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~5.1.0",
        "@angular/core": "~5.1.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~5.1.0",
        "@angular/http": "~5.1.0",
        "@angular/material": "^5.0.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~5.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~5.1.0",
        "@angular/router": "~5.1.0",
        "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client": "https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript.git",
        "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types": "https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-typescript-typings.git",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
        "@types/hellojs": "1.15.0",
        "angular2-emoji-picker": "^1.4.6",
        "angular2-infinite-scroll": "^0.3.5",
        "angular2-isotope": "0.0.2",
        "angular2-lightbox": "^1.2.1",
        "angular2-masonry": "^0.4.0",
        "angular2-moment": "^1.6.0",
        "angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc0",
        "core-js": "^2.5.3",
        "firebase": "^3.9.*",
        "firebaseui": "^2.5.1",
        "firebaseui-angular": "^2.5.2",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "hellojs": "1.16.1",
        "intro.js": "^2.8.0-alpha.1",
        "ng2-imageupload": "^1.4.2",
        "ng2-img-cropper": "^0.9.0",
        "ng2-img-max": "^2.1.9",
        "ng2-translate": "^5.0.0",
        "ngx-owl-carousel": "^2.0.2",
        "rxjs": "^5.5.5",
        "script-loader": "^0.7.2",
        "zone.js": "0.8.18"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "1.3.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~5.1.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "~5.1.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
        "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
        "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
        "karma": "~1.7.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
        "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "~5.1.2",
        "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
        "tslint": "~5.3.2",
        "typescript": "~2.4.2"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hey there, can you inspect the browser console to check if there are any errors there that could shed some light on this issue?

Comment: I didnt see any error :(

Comment: Can you check the network log? There must some error there or some request that is stalling. One thing to note, there was an issue with the closure builder used which might be related: https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/260